# How to remove iOS native log prefixes from Flutter console output

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm working on a Flutter app and facing an issue with the console output on iOS. Every line printed or logged using [logger](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) from the Flutter framework is preceded by an iOS message, which makes tracing the logs very difficult. I think the problem started after I created flavors for my app, but can't be sure. The log output looks like this:

`2023-04-29 11:21:41.997198+0100 <Package Name>[4279:1219892] flutter: My app log message`

I want to remove the iOS native log prefixes (i.e., the `2023-04-29 11:21:41.997198+0100 <Package Name>[4279:1219892] flutter:` part) from the console output to make it more readable.

I've tried disabling `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` in Xcode, but it didn't help. Filtering logs with `grep` is not what I'm looking for, as I want to remove the prefixes, not just filter the logs.

How can I remove these native log prefixes from the console output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. When creating a flavor, I had changed the `PRODUCT_NAME` in the Build Settings from "Runner" to the name of each flavor ("MyApp" for production and "MyApp Staging" for staging).

Introducing a new user-defined variable called `FLAVOR_APP_NAME` and using that as the Bundle Display Name and setting the `PRODUCT_NAME` to "Runner" fixed the problem.

I don't know the exact cause of the problem. If there is anyone who can improve this answer by providing an explanation, it will be more useful for everyone.